# How can I change the length of my ffmpeg video? The concatenation is not working

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

I am trying to use the ffmpeg library whereby I take three images, and make a 9 second video of them. However, it is just showing the first video for three seconds, then finishing. What in my code do I need to change? The code uses AWS Lambda to store the files in temporary storage. I've logged everything before, and it all seems to be working. I have a feeling it is this line of code that is not working: `.outputOptions(["-c:v libx264", "-t 12", "-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-vf scale=1280:720", "-r 1"])` combined with the concatenation process.

```
async function processImages(imageStreams) {
  for (let i = 0; i < imageStreams.length; i++) {
    await processSingleImage(imageStreams[i], `/tmp/temp_video_${i}.mp4`, i);
  }
  await concatenateVideos(imageStreams.length);
}


async function processSingleImage(imageStream, outputPath, index) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const command = ffmpeg(imageStream);
    command
      .outputOptions(["-c:v libx264", "-t 12", "-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-vf scale=1280:720", "-r 1"])
      .on("end", () => {
        resolve();
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error(`Error during processing of image ${index}:`, err);
        reject(err);
      })
      .saveToFile(outputPath);
  });
}

async function concatenateVideos(numberOfVideos) {
  const fileList = "/tmp/file_list.txt";
  let fileContent = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfVideos; i++) {
    fileContent += `file '/tmp/temp_video_${i}.mp4'\n`;
  }

  await fs.writeFile(fileList, fileContent);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg()
      .input(fileList)
      .inputOptions(["-f concat", "-safe 0"])
      .outputOptions(["-c copy"])
      .saveToFile("/tmp/output.mp4");
  });
}
```

Comment: Do all of your calls to processSingleImage correctly output a mp4 file that plays?

Comment: I haven't confirmed this yet, however, when I do `.outputOptions(["-c:v libx264", "-pix_fmt yuv420p", "-vf scale=1280:720", "-framerate 1"])`, I can see all of the images within a 1 second video.

Answer (score 1):

The end solution involved not creating the videos separately, but concatenating the images like so:

```
async function concat(bucketName, imageKeys) {
  const imageStreams = await Promise.all(
    imageKeys.map(async (key, i) => {
      const command = new GetObjectCommand({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: key });
      const response = await s3.send(command);
      // Define the temporary file path based on the index
      const tempFilePath = `/tmp/${i}.png`;

      // Write the image data to the temporary file
      await fs.writeFile(tempFilePath, response.Body);

      // Return the file path to be used later
      return tempFilePath;
    })
  );

  // Create a file list content with durations
  let fileContent = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < imageStreams.length; i++) {
    fileContent += `file '${imageStreams[i]}'\nduration 3\n`;

    // Check if it's the last image, and if so, add it again
    if (i === imageStreams.length - 1) {
      fileContent += `file '${imageStreams[i]}'\nduration 3\n`;
    }
  }

  // Define the file path for the file list
  const fileListPath = "/tmp/file_list.txt";

  // Write the file list content to the file
  await fs.writeFile(fileListPath, fileContent);

  try {
    await fs.writeFile(fileListPath, fileContent);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error writing file list:", error);
    throw error;
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ffmpeg()
      .input(fileListPath)
      .inputOptions(["-f concat", "-safe 0"])
      .outputOptions("-c copy")
      .on("end", () => {
        resolve();
      })
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.error("Error during video concatenation:", err);
        reject(err);
      })
      .saveToFile("/tmp/output.mp4");
  });
}
```